# How to update a UITableViewCell during re-ordering

Tags: ios, uitableview

While dragging a `UITableViewCell`, the delegate method `- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath` gets called . Within this delegate method I can set properties for the selected cell depending on its `proposedDestinationIndexPath`.

My question is now how to update the cell content during moving it. I can get the cell updated after releasing the move handle, but I would need to show updated values while moving up & down depending on its position (`proposedDestinationIndexPath`).

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Thank you @Flex_Addicted.
Was my first post here Stackoverflow ... will take care about formatting in future posts.

Answer (score 3):

You could change the content of the cell in `tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:`.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Moving Cell to %d %d", proposedDestinationIndexPath.section, proposedDestinationIndexPath.row];
    return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
}
```

However, if you don't actually try to move the cell to a new indexPath this method is not called. So if you just move the cell some pixels up and down you can't change your text. But I guess you shouldn't do that anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. What I would like to achieve is an hierarchical list which has indentation depending on the nesting level. Moving a cell should therefore update the indentation as well as update an icon (that symbolises if the cell is a node with children or just a child without further children) in the selected cell (realtime while moving). There is an app called "Outline" that does this ... so it must be somehow possible.

Comment: I don't need to update depending on the pixel position, but depending on the proposedDestinationIndexPath. Therefore I use the delegate methode 'tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:' to set the properties on the cell. The cell just doesn't reflect the updated properties while it is still moving. I have tried 'setNeedsDisplay', but it doesn't update either.

Comment: Maybe you could show us your code for targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath. I just tried Matthias's solution and was able to modify the cell content while moving to different proposedDestinationIndexPath's.